# How to fix the nothing to commit message in git when you have code to commit

Tags: github

I am using visual studio code and have been getting this error message when
I tried to check in code and yes I made some changes to my code

```
    On branch develop
    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
```

nothing to commit, working tree clean

I have code to commit. Not sure what this message means?

Kindly assist

Comment: Have you done `git add`?

Comment: Yes I did git add , git commit -am "comment", and git push